# How to customize module loading behaviors based on user's role in SCSF

Tags: scsf, role-base-authorization

Does anyone know how to customize module loading behaviors based on user's role in SCSF?

Answer (score 0):

I believe what you are asking is to be able to load SCSF modules dynamically instead of using the default method (which reads the module list from ProfileCatalog.xml).

I've tried the method outlined in these two articles and found it to work fairly well  Hopefully they can be of some help to you.

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/mszcool/archive/2005/12/20/505976.aspx

http://aspadvice.com/blogs/krishna_kishore/pages/Dynamically-Loading-Modules-in-SCSF.aspx

Hope that helps!